# Connecting to MySQL database located at (pythonanywhere.com) from app located at (heroku.com)

Tags: mysql, heroku, deployment, remote-access, pythonanywhere

I created a webb app and deployed it at Heroku. So far, so good. Now I need to integrate it with the MySQL database which is located at pythonanywhere.com.

I tried the following command (which is what I managed to find when googling for accessing a remote MySQL database from Heroku):

> heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=mysql2://PYTHONANYWHERE_USER:DATABASE-HOST-ADDRESS/DATABASE-NAME--app HEROKU-APP-NAME

Whenever I run this command from the console in Heroku, I get the following message:

> bash: heroku: command not found

Have anyone tried connecting to a pythonanywhere MySQL database from Heroku before? Can you show how you did this step-by-step?

The reason why I want to access the PythonAnywhere database (and not just host it on Heroku) is that a lot of the backend is written on PythonAnywhere and stored on that database.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you installed the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli)?

Comment: Also, why are you trying to use a remote database on PythonAnywhere? Heroku has many database addons, including some that provide MySQL.

Comment: How do you mean? My app is deployed at Heroku.com and I'm trying to access the PythonAnywhere database from Heroku (in the cloud)

Comment: The reason for having the database on PythonAnywhere is that all the backend code is running there. We wanted to have the frontend there as well, but PythonAnywhere lacked support for Node.js projects

Comment: The `heroku` command is the Heroku CLI. You'll have to install it if you want to use it.

Comment: …I'm confused. What is your Node.js code if not back-end code? (Front-end code almost certainly shouldn't be talking to your database.)

Comment: I'm sorry Chris, I don't fully understand. I deployed the app from C9 (in which the Heroku CLI comes pre-installed). The app is now deployed at Heroku. I want to access the PythonAnywhere database from Heroku. Should I install the Heroku CLI on PythonAnywhere and run the "heroku config" command on PythonAnywhere? I was under the impression that I should run that command on Heroku.

Comment: Forgive me for being unclear. I made a dashboard which shows predictions made by an artificial neural network. All that data is in a database at PythonAnywhere. I want to show that data on my dashboard which is hosted at Heroku

Comment: If you're seeing `bash: heroku: command not found` then you don't have the Heroku CLI installed properly. I don't know about C9, but if the Heroku CLI is preinstalled there then `heroku config:add...` should give you a different result.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Chris. I'm running the heroku config command from the console INSIDE Heroku :-)

Comment: Ah. You should never need to run `heroku` from there. Try running your `heroku config:add` command _from C9_.

Comment: Ah. Thank you - much better now! So I got this output: ----
Setting DATABASE_URL and restarting ⬢ immense-gorge-91345... done, v5
DATABASE_URL: mysql2://.... ----

Do I use the process.env.DATABASE_URL as host when I connect to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `heroku` command is provided by the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli), and should be installed and run *from your local machine*. Running `heroku` commands directly from a dyno (e.g., via `heroku run bash`) won't work.

Once you've set `DATABASE_URL` using `heroku config` you should be able to access it from your code via `process.env.DATABASE_URL`.

Comment: Thanks Chris! One last question: Do you know what would be the ip in:

>>heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=mysql2://username:password@ip.goes.here/data_base_name --app heroku-app-name<<

I'm not sure that the ip==database host address in PythonAnywhere?

Comment: Yes, the hostname should work. Note that all of this is subject to access rules (network-level and database level), so it may not work.